# Ag Silver Searcher: output file name when used in while-loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, ag

When using `ag` (*edit: version 0.33.0*) in a Bash while loop I can't make it show me any file names:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<__m | while read mod; do ag --nogroup --filename --ignore=local "^use $mod" ./; done
CGI
CGI::Push
__m
```

Output:

```
use 4.08;
use 4.08;
...
```

When executing it directly on the command line it works:

```
ag --nogroup --filename --ignore=local "^use CGI" ./
```

Output:

```
dir/file/ModA.pm:12:use CGI 4.08;
dir/file/ModB.pm:1:use CGI 4.08;
```

How can I always get the filenames inline?

Comment: Looks weird. Do you have any aliases or functions controlling ag? What does `type -a ag` show?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could avoid using `while read`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for mod in CGI CGI::Push ; do
     ag --nogroup --filename --ignore=local "^use $mod" ./
done
```

I believe your problem is actually because of a bug(?) in `ag`.  In `options.c`, it does:

```
rv = fstat(fileno(stdin), &statbuf);
if (rv == 0) {
    if (S_ISFIFO(statbuf.st_mode) || S_ISREG(statbuf.st_mode)) {
        opts.search_stream = 1;
    }
}
```

Since you're running under `while read`, your `stdin` is not a TTY, so `opts.search_stream` ends up being set to 1.  This causes the `opts.print_path` to be set to `PATH_PRINT_NOTHING`.  Thus, your paths won't print when run this way.  Maybe `ag` needs an option to forcibly allow this?

Comment: Thank you, you save my days for making ag work instead of grep (could've taken days literalilly)

Answer (score 0):

As per @eddiem said, use workaround instead of **while read** since **while read** is the culprit. Well, at least the way below works fine with me. ( ag version 2.2.0 on MacOS)

```
IFS=$'\n'
for line in `cat $filename`; do
    ag --nogroup --numbers $line
done
exit 0
```

Again, thanks to @eddiem and all the credit goes to him.